# adding a slideshow to emberJS template page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, flexslider

**EDIT: Did some more digging around and emberJS doesn't allow inline script execution. How would I go about creating a slideshow? Do I create a component?**

I've only started out with emberJS. I've followed the guides on the website by Ember and looked on here to learn, but I've found myself in a bit of a dead end and I need your help!

This is the situation:
I want to add a slideshow to one of my templates. Now, to the best of my abilities I have added the slideshow .js and .css using 'BOWER INSTALL' and then edited my 'ember-cli-build.js' to reference the app.import for those two dependencies.

It's a basic website pages such as 'About Me', 'Services', 'Contact Us'. Nothing fancy. Say I want to add this slideshow to the 'Services' page, at first when I visit the site it loads up with no issues but when I switch between the templates/pages using {{#link-to}} function it disappears and won't load again.

Can anyone explain how I should add inline scripting on templates?

Sorry for the beginners question.

**In order for me to run the slide show I need to execute the following script after the DOM elements on the page.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
      });
</script>
```

**The HTML is as follows:**

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/0889d8/000000" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/c1a4f0/ffffff" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/8b4513/000000" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use the slick addon, but ran into issues with it. So I created another ember addon that wraps the [jquery unslider](http://unslider.com/) plugin. Check out [ember-cli-unslider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-unslider).

See the [simple demo](http://jamiechong.github.io/ember-cli-unslider/).

The `un-slider` component expects an array of slides. Within its block you must define the HTML content used for each slide.

```
{{#un-slider slides=model as |slide|}}
<img src="{{slide.url}}"/>
{{/un-slider}}
```

In the above example, `model` could look like this:

```
[
  { url: 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=slide 1&w=600&h=400' }, 
  { url: 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=slide 2&w=600&h=400' }, 
  { url: 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=slide 3&w=600&h=400' }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an ember addon that already does that: [ember-cli-slick](https://github.com/laantorchaweb/ember-cli-slick)

Install it using :

```
ember install ember-cli-slick
```

You can use it in your template like this:

```
{{#slick-slider autoplay=true arrows=false}}
    <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
{{/slick-slider}}
```

If you want to learn how to make a slideshow component look at the source code here: 
https://github.com/laantorchaweb/ember-cli-slick/blob/master/addon/components/slick-slider.js

This is just a wrapper component for the slick.js plugin . You would do the same for the flexslider plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for and now i'll start digging through ember-cli addons to see if I can save time and learn new things. Am I right in thinking If I want to say, create my own jQuery function I need to wrap this inside a component?

Comment: Usually when you want to apply a jquery function over some DOM elements,  you do it in the didInsertElement function of a component. Check this tutorial out: http://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-initialize-a-jquery-component-with-ember-js/

Comment: @BriscBogdan I need to use asNavFor option how can we pass the options to the slider ?